# No module named <module_name>

Tags: python, module

I have the following code all in a file named baz.py

```
# foo.py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self,foo):
        self.foo = foo

# bar.py
class Bar:
    def __init__(self,bar):
        self.bar = bar
    # some functions

# baz.py
# calling some functions from Bar
```

I would like to organize my project in the following manner:

```
project|-model|-foo.py
              |-bar.py
              |-__init__.py
       |-test |-baz.py
       |-__init__.py
```

And run baz.py

To do so I added at the top of baz.py the following

```
from project.model import foo, bar
```

However I get the error "No module named project" when using

```
C:\...\project> & C:/Python39/python.exe "c:/.../project/test/baz.py"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you're running the script with `project` as your working directory, and python does not find a directory named `project` inside of `project`. Have you tried to modify your line to:

```
from model import foo, bar
```

Since `model` is inside the `project` directory. Or you can call the function from the parent directory of `project`.

Comment: I've tried but I get a similar issue: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'model'